# Why can't ignore some files?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

This is my .gitignore for my Android Studio

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project

# Android Studio
.idea/
.gradle
*.iml
.DS_Store
```

When I clean my project,it appears some files
[image]
[image]
How to modify .gitignore to ignore the files?

Answer (score 0):

From your local path for git repo (which I am assuming here is ~/Documents/project_android)
add path to ignore.

`#Cookie Files 
Cookies3/*`

and save

Answer (score 0):

add

`folderToRemove/`

OR

`*.FileFormat to remove`

Answer (score 0):

The `build/` rule should already ignore those files.

.gitignore won't ignore objects already added to the index. Use `git rm --cached <filename>` to remove a file from the index but not from the working tree.

Comment: thx,but when I "git rm" the files they're still in the working tree.

Comment: If you want to remove them from the working tree also, `git rm` without the `--cached`.